# Filter followed tail to file using grep and redirect

Tags: linux, redirect, grep, stdout, tail

I want to get the output of

`tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log | grep "trace1"`

into a file. But

`tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log | grep "trace1" > output.txt`

does not work, while the first command gives an output in my terminal window as expected.

I guess it has to do with the follow-parameter, because if I omit the "-f", the output file is created.

But why is this so and how can I achieve my goal?

Regards,
Axel

Comment: What is your goal?  `tail -f` provides ongoing output;  when do you want to stop writing data to `output.txt`?

Comment: It seems like perhaps you want `grep trace1 /var/log/apache2/error.log > output.txt`, and then when you want to see what's happening do `tail -f output.txt` in another shell.

Comment: Yes, I indeed want to have an ongoing output so I can stop the proces after a week or two and see what is in the output.txt file. So I can see all the "trace1" that occured during this timespan.

Comment: As a workaround I installed a cronjob that uses `grep trace1 /var/log/apache2/error.log > output.txt` on a daily base. Anyhow, the question why the followed tail output is not written to the output file still remains.

Comment: `grep` is writing its data line buffered when it's writing to a tty, and block buffered when it's writing to a regular file.  Wait long enough, and data will get written....but it will be stale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log | grep "trace1" | tee -a output.txt
```